How to get better image quality when converting from pdf?
I have a code that converts range from the spreadsheet into a image and send it as a repot. It works well but the quality of the image is low. The PDF I am getting is in really good quality but the inline image gets bad. Is there any way to improve quality of the image?
By now I have tried just to make fonts in the spreadsheet bigger. The fonts are now 36 size and the quality got better but it is still not the best so I would like to know if there is a way to solve the problem within the code.
async function convertPDFToPNG_(blob) {
  // Convert PDF to PNG images.
  const cdnjs = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnjs).getContentText()); // Load pdf-lib
  const setTimeout = function (f, t) { // Overwrite setTimeout with Google Apps Script.
    Utilities.sleep(t);
    return f();
  }
  const data = new Uint8Array(blob.getBytes());
  const pdfData = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(data);
  const pageLength = pdfData.getPageCount();
  console.log(`Total pages: ${pageLength}`);
  const obj = { imageBlobs: [], fileIds: [] };
  for (let i = 0; i < pageLength; i++) {
    console.log(`Processing page: ${i + 1}`);
    const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
    const [page] = await pdfDoc.copyPages(pdfData, [i]);
    pdfDoc.addPage(page);
    const bytes = await pdfDoc.save();
    const blob = Utilities.newBlob([...new Int8Array(bytes)], MimeType.PDF, `sample${i + 1}.pdf`);
    const id = DriveApp.createFile(blob).getId();
    Utilities.sleep(4000); // This is used for preparing the thumbnail of the created file.
    const link = Drive.Files.get(id, { fields: "thumbnailLink" }).thumbnailLink;
    if (!link) {
      throw new Error("In this case, please increase the value of 3000 in Utilities.sleep(3000), and test it again.");
    }
    const imageBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link.replace(/\=s\d*/, "=s1000")).getBlob().setName(`page${i + 1}.png`);
    obj.imageBlobs.push(imageBlob);
    obj.fileIds.push(id);
  }
  obj.fileIds.forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true));
  return obj.imageBlobs;
}

// Please run this function.

async function sendReport() {

  // Retrieve Spreadsheet and Sheet objects.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("IDIDIDIDIDID");
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");

  // Retrieve PDF blob.
  const url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=pdf&range=B2:S52&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}&size=6&portrait=false&`;
  const pdfBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob();

  const SOURCE_TEMPLATE = pdfBlob;
  const TARGET_FOLDER = "FOLDER-IDIDIDIDID";

  // Use a method for converting all pages in a PDF file to PNG images.
  const blob = pdfBlob
  const imageBlobs = await convertPDFToPNG_(blob);

  // As a sample, create PNG images as PNG files.
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(TARGET_FOLDER);
  //imageBlobs.forEach(b => folder.createFile(b));




const reportDate = sheet.getRange(84, 6).getValue();
const month = reportDate.getMonth() + 1;
const day = reportDate.getDate();
const sender = sheet.getRange(84, 7).getValue();
  // I modified the below script.
  const htmlBody = `
    <html>
      <body>
        <p>TEST</p>
        <p>${month}${day}REPORT</p>
        
        <img src="cid:inlineImage" />
        <p>${sender}</p>
      </body>
    </html>
  `;

  const inlineImage = imageBlobs[0].setName("inlineImage");
  const rangeTo = sheet.getRange(84, 4, ss.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  const emailTo = rangeTo.reduce(function(prev, next) {
  return prev.concat(next);
});

 const rangeCC = sheet.getRange(84, 5, ss.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  const emailCC = rangeCC.reduce(function(prev, next) {
  return prev.concat(next);
});

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailTo.join(","),
    cc: emailCC.join(",") || null,
    bcc: "" || null,
    subject: "REPORT　　"+month+"/"+day+,
    //body: "TEST",
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
    inlineImages: { inlineImage: inlineImage },
    attachments: [pdfBlob]
  });
  
}


also, did you try changing "=s1000" to "=s2000" with "size=10"?

@player0 changing those parameters does not help...
